# Cannot get authentication working in IIS 8.5

Tags: windows-authentication, iis-8.5

We have installed Basic and Windows authentication for IIS 8.5 on our Windows 2012 server but cannot get the server to prompt the client for credentials.

Under the "Authentication" feature we have only 2 options (despite restarting IIS numerous times):

- Anonymous Authentication: Disabled
- ASP.NET Impersonation: Disabled

When we set anonymous to Disabled we get a 401 but no Authenticate headers. When we Enable it we get a 200 but are anonymous.

We've tried all sorts of settings in `web.config` and here is the current situation:

`<system.web>
    <authentication mode="Windows" />
        <authorization>
            <deny users="?"/>
        </authorization>
    </system.web>`

Answer (score 3):

Solved it by running the IIS Admin console as an administrator (thanks to question #8067448). For some reason the new authentication options (Basic and Windows) now appear and could be enabled. Sheesh Microsoft!

Comment: I don't think you need to run it as an administrator, you just need to close and reopen the IIS Manager after installing Windows Authentication on the server. That is what just happened to me.