# How to Get Authentication working on IIS 8.5 after migration from IIS6

Tags: asp.net, authentication, iis, iis-8

I have migrated a asp.net web site from IIS6 to IIS8.5. Almost all issues are fixed. But it seems that the identity of the user gets lost.

Related questions I found:

[Cannot get authentication working in IIS 8.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29394827/cannot-get-authentication-working-in-iis-8-5)

[Configure windows Authentication in IIS 8.5 on Windows Server 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36503115/configure-windows-authentication-in-iis-8-5-on-windows-server-2012)

[Receiving login prompt using integrated windows authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5402381/receiving-login-prompt-using-integrated-windows-authentication)

When I open the webpage from the server IE browser there is no login prompt (which would be fine if the integrated authentication was used)
When I open the webpage from a remote client I should get a login prompt for authentication (since the user on the client does not exist on the server). But there is none.

On the old platform IE6 was used. On the new platform IE is used with compatibility mode

In the old web page integrated windows authentication (only) is enabled and working.
In the new web page on IIS 8.5 I tried all kind of settings but none seem to do the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out that actually the authentication itself is working. 
This link was very helpful finding this out:

https://forums.asp.net/t/1179997.aspx?Get+Username+for+logged+in+user

But the user name gets lost in a different way. I will close this question and post another one.